# reserve-port-plugin vs new ServerSocket(0) for test

Tags: java, maven, sockets

I have Junit test which starts a socket server and send requests to it. Usually I'm using [reserve-port-plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/reserve-network-port-mojo.html) for Maven to allocate random port and pass it via system properties to test. But now I read in documentation that `new ServerSocket(0)` allocates new socket with "automatically allocated" port number. [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#ServerSocket-int-) says:

> A port number of 0 means that the port number is automatically allocated, typically from an ephemeral port range.

It looks much easier to use `new ServerSocket(0)` than configuring Maven plugin for that, but it's not clear how exaclty this "automatically allocation" works. E.g. does it check for open permission before allocating? Is it identical to use these two approaches for random port allocating in tests?

Answer (score 1):

You could read the source code to understand how they work, though I suspect there are some per-OS variations that I would caution against relying on.

I think it's probably more useful to understand WHY to use one vs. the other.  Using `new ServerSocket(0)` is easier in a small scope, but could lead to weird bindings/dependencies depending on your system under test.

If, for example, what you're trying to do is start up a full webapp, and run selenium tests against it, I'd recommend the maven solution.  Trying to provide a server socket into a servlet container would be either difficult and brittle, or potentially impossible.

On the other hand, for a very contained socket type test, the `new ServerSocket(0)` approach is probably simpler.